# pgfplots: Position X-axis when drawing negative parabola

Tags: pgfplots

I've been wanting to draw a parabola using `pgfplots` resembling the image below.

[image: image of parabola]

However, as I try to replicate this, the x-axis is always touching said parabola.
Below is the code (`\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}` is the only preamble line of concern):

```latex
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                domain=-2:5,
                smooth,
                axis lines=middle,
                xlabel=\(x\),
                ylabel=\(y\),
                ticks=none,
                grid=major,
                scaled ticks=false,
            ]
            \addplot[black, thick] {-x^2 + 3 * x - 12};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

After Complilation:
[image: failed parabola]

Is there any way to position the x-axis in the middle (as seen in the image)?

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

- I cleaned your code a bit including moving options from `axis` to `addplot` which seems more intuitive to me.
- **Main Point:** I believe that you need to **add `xmin` and friends** to achieve your goal.
- I also recommend beginning with a version with x/y ticks so that you see "where you are".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines = middle,
                xlabel= $x$,
                ylabel= $y$,
                %ticks = none,
                grid = major,
                scaled ticks = false,
                xmin = -3,
                xmax = 6,
                ymin = -20,
                ymax = 2,
            ]
            \addplot[
                black, 
                thick, 
                domain = -2:5, 
                smooth,
                ]
                {-x^2 + 3 * x - 12};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                xlabel= $x$,
                ylabel= $y$,
                ticks = none,
                grid = major,
                scaled ticks = false,
                xmin = -3,
                xmax = 6,
                ymin = -20,
                ymax = 2,
            ]
            \addplot[
                black, 
                thick, 
                domain = -2:5, 
                smooth,
                ]
                {-x^2 + 3 * x - 12};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}    
    
\end{document}
```